# Entities are not found

Tags: spring-roo

I use STS3.4 and Spring Roo1.2.2. When I open the Roo Shell, I got the message:

```
roo> Encountered " ";" "; "" at line 52, column 67.
Was expecting one of:
"instanceof" ...
"(" ...
")" ...
```

It is not a new project and everything has worked fine.
Now I want to add a new field in an existing Entity. But when i type in shell "focus --class ~.server." and press CTRL+SPACE, the entities are not found. I enter the class and other options myself, but it dose not work. I got the message above again.

I have tried Spring Roo 1.2.4 and got 
`NullPointerException at com.github.antlrjavaparser.adapter.BlockContextAda pter.adapt(BlockContextAdapter.java:33)`.
 And i can still not add a new field.

I have also tried direct in the Entity

```
@Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "int default 2")
private int status;
```

but not work.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong or how I could debug this?

Comment: Are you using JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging i find the reason. This parser Exception is because of a special character "€" in a @Service class.